# How to put a right amount of characters in one mobile page(page and font sizes will change on different mobiles)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

This question that I'm going to ask is hard to express, so please correct me if you think my expression doesn't reflect what I want to ask, thanks in advance.

I am working on a eBook mobile app. Things I need to take into consideration are :
1. screen size
2. font size
3. how many paragraphs I should put into one page according to current screen size and font size.

I'd like to use a bigger font size on a bigger screen, so I don't know how to decide how many paragraphs should be put into one page.
I have the data as a whole article but have no idea when and where to break it into pages.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome.

**Update:**

Okay, let me make it more detailed.

Say I have an article:

```
var arti = "Stack Overflow is a website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[2][3] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,[4][5] as a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts Exchange. The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.[6]
It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming.[7][8][9] The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions, and, through membership and active participation, to vote questions and answers up or down and edit questions and answers in a fashion similar to a wiki or digg.[10] Users of Stack Overflow can earn reputation points and "badges"; for example, a person is awarded 10 reputation points for receiving an "up" vote on an answer given to a question, and can receive badges for their valued contributions,[11] which represents a kind of gamification of the traditional Q&A site or forum. All user-generated content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribute-ShareAlike license.[12]
As of August 2013, Stack Overflow has over 1,900,000 registered users and more than 5,500,000 questions.[13][14] Based on the type of tags assigned to questions, the top eight most discussed topics on the site are: C#, Java, PHP, JavaScript, Android, jQuery, C++ and Python.[15]";
```

and the screen size of the mobile I'm using to test my app is 1280*760 which can only display around X characters in one screen.

So my program should break the content of the arti at the end of the Xth, 2*Xth , 3*Xth, ... etc. characters.

So the questions are
 I don't know how to calculate the X.

Comment: `overflow: auto;` ???  Not sure what you need.

Comment: are you asking how to decide where to break the text, or how to calculate how much text is on the page, or ??? have you got any code to start with?

Comment: Have a look into using 'ems' as the values for containing element widths and heights. Then you can set layout based on font size more accurately

Comment: @user3117575  cannot use overflow:auto. it's a mobile app, so it shouldn't allow users to scroll the screen and the size of this app should be same as the size of screen.

Comment: @norlesh yes, I'm asking how to decide where to break the text so the rest of the text goes into the following pages.

Comment: @RobSedge what's 'ems'??

Comment: I don't think we can help you, your question is very broad... find some open open source code that does some of the things you want and learn how they did it.

Comment: @norlesh I am using Swiper at http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php, I don't even know what should be the key words to use to search for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest bigger chars for smaller screens!

Comment: okay, but how to decide when I should break the whole article as the fixed size screen cannot contain all characters?

Comment: I think that you should use mm as unit for the font-size. I dont't know about this specific question, I probably would estimate the amount of chars depending on the screen size mm or inches and split the text into an array for every page.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment. ( not an answer as subjective )

Using ems for width can tell us how many font characters wide a containing element is.

consider

```
<style>

body { font size: 0.8em; } /* roughly about 14 px */
.container {  width: 30em; } /* 1em now equals 0.8 */

</style>
```

we now know *( or as close as possible )* , that the `<div class="container"> .. </div>`  can hold text with lines of ( close to ) 30 characters.

The good part here is that if we change the font size :

```
<style>

body { font size: 1.2em; }

</style>
```

The container width also changes and we **retain** our set number of characters per line. 
Because of this we have a connection between layout and typography and have control over "fixing" paragraph lengths and spacing within our designs.

Quite useful when we need to calculate heights, widths and our designed 'page breaks' of layout elements based on layouts that adapt to different sizes and are dealing with dynamic text and font sizes.

Comment: Hi Rob, thx for your help. I don't understand why " if we change the font size, The container width also changes "? And also, it's a mobile app so I cannot let the content of a container squeeze the whole app, because if I did so, it will not look like a mobile app but a web page.

Comment: Thanks, because the width is set at the font size ( eg not pixels ). Not an all in one solution to question, sorry, just answering the comment question on ems and is related to problems around dynamic layouts and font sizes.

Comment: Franva, though You will have bette answers if you provide the complete HTML layout and CSS in the question. There is no outthebox 'pagebreaker' answer, it all depends on your design. With that , we can see what you are trying to achieve and there wil be a bespoke  CSS / javascript answer to it.

Comment: Hi Rob, thx a lot for your help, I'll update my code once I get back to home

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution is to adjust a div to the size of the viewport of the device and use https://github.com/olegskl/fitText